# Android USB Storage missing

Tags: android, permissions, local-storage, mount

I have an odd problem with my rooted/CM10.1 Android phone.
I realized a problem with my storage a while ago. Until now I believed it would be a hardware defect. When booting my internal USB-Storage is missing (not the external SD card). All I have is my "Internal Storage" and the external SD. So all data (like camera pictures and some apps) on this "drive" are not available.

But after a while I realized, when connecting the phone to the PC - it is still not there then initially. But after disconnecting (and thus remounting the devices) it suddenly is there.
So I understood it as a problem with the mounting or something like that.
When looking at the log while booting I found messages like this:

*I/DefContainer-JNI(2799): error opening: /storage/sdcard0: Permission denied*

So I came to the idea that a program takes the permissions but does not release them until remounting.

When booting, there are not really any suspicios apps running. So I dont see the problem there.
Has anyone an idea how to "remount" the internal Storage without connecting it to the pc? I tried fixing the permissions of the file system already. This wasn't working! I just bought the ROM Toolbox. I thought this tool might do it, but I have no idea where to start.

Thanks for your help,
 Tobias

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it took me a while but I think I have found the problem (or at least a solution).
Another user was describing a problem which reminded me on my own here:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=601340

It looks like the "checking for errors" is locking the card until it is finished with the scan. As described in this discussion, there might be a problem with the fsck_msdos file
When I eventually deleted this file from *system /bin* everything worked fine.

So I assume the checking process was in a kind of deadlock and couldn't finish the checking to mount the sdcard.

I hope this helps to whoever might have the same problem.

Regards,
 Tobias